# Get the next largest time from the table for a set of inputs

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql table like

```
Name  |  age |     time
------+------+---------
x     |   23 | 21:00:01
y     |   67 | 23:34:43
z     |   90 | 12:45:34
a     |   45 | 21:10:10
b     |    3 | 23:45:00
```

Now I need to find the name and age for a input which has time just greater than the given input.

Say I have an input 21:00:01 then output will be 21:10:10. I can write this query but I have a huge list of inputs and every time I cannot execute a query for each input date.

What I need is a query which take the input list as input and return me the next big time against each inputs. I am stuck here any solutions please

I am trying to get the output like this when there is a where clause like time in ("21:00:01",...)

```
Name  |  age |     time  |    nexttime   |   nextname   |
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
x     |   23 | 21:00:01  | 21:10:10      | a
y     |   67 | 23:34:43  | 23:45:00      | b
z     |   90 | 12:45:34  | 21:00:01      | x
a     |   45 | 21:10:10  | 23:34:43      | y
b     |    3 | 23:45:00  |               |
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the inputs into a table, say `InputTimes`.  Then you can do this as a correlated subquery:

```
select it.*,
       (select name
        from table t
        where t.time > it.time -- removed =
        order by t.time
        limit 1
       ) as name,
       (select age
        from table t
        where t.time > it.time -- removed =
        order by t.time
        limit 1
       ) as age
from InputTimes it;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to get this result?

```
Name  |  age |     time  |    nexttime   |   nextname   |
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
x     |   23 | 21:00:01  | 21:10:10      | a
y     |   67 | 23:34:43  | 23:45:00      | b
z     |   90 | 12:45:34  | 21:00:01      | x
a     |   45 | 21:10:10  | 23:34:43      | y
b     |    3 | 23:45:00  |               |
```

Can be done by

```
select
t.name,
t.age,
t.time,
(select top 1 t2.time from myTable t2 where t2.time > t.time order by t2.time) as nexttime,
(select top 1 t2.name from myTable t2 where t2.time > t.time order by t2.time) as nextname
from myTable t
```

Comment: Thnx OlleR,  I need the same as above.

Comment: Post updated with SQL-statement

Comment: Oh, just saw that the previous post just gave the answer :)